# How to implement multi-level model references in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I have the model structure below. I need to add the validation so only the correct user of the restaurant and the restaurant campaigns can edit/delete them each.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :restaurants, dependent: :destroy
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    validates  :user_id, presence: true

    has_many :campaigns, dependent: :destroy
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

I recall there is a process for enabling the 'step-over' of the central model, this case the restaurant model, so that one can make reference to the campaigns model from the users model directly such as:

```
@user.campaigns.find_by(params[:id])
```

How can I enable this allowance.

**Addition**

What I am trying to do is enable this method to allow only the user that owns the campaigns to edit/delete/view:

```
    def correct_user
        @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
        @campaign = @user.campaigns.find_by(params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url if @campaign.nil?
    end
```

where then in the controller I have:

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:index, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
```

But this method, though no errors are present does not prevent any other user from seeing the campaigns of another user. Therefore the routing with `@campaign = @user.campaigns.find_by(params[:id])` cannot be correct.

Comment: has_many :campaigns, through: restaurants

Comment: Is that all it takes?

Comment: Yes - that'll build out the sql for you.  Look more into 'has_many through' for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: You would also need to change `@user.campaigns.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nested routes like

```
resources :restaurants do
  resources :campaigns
end
```

Then the URLs would contain the restaurant_id, eg:

```
restaurants/:restaurant_id/campaigns/:id/edit
```

Then you can do this in your controller

```
@restaurant = current_user.restaurants.find(params[:restaurant_id])
@campaign = @restaurant.campaigns.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: This does not work, it returns null for both `@restaurant` and `@campaign`

Comment: If calling the current_user method doesn't throw an error, and you are able to call the .restaurants method, that may mean the current_user has no restaurants.

Comment: No, the current user has a few restaurants

Comment: @Eatlon, Can you show the routes and the controller action which you are hitting?